# Every non-constant harmonic function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is surjective.

Tags: analysis

Every non-constant harmonic function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is surjective.

Does this work?

So, assume by contradiction that $f$ is not surjective, i.e. there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ that is not attained by $f$. Since $f$ is harmonic and non-constant, one consequence of the Louiville theorem is that it can not be bounded from above or under. In particular, there must exist $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x_1)>y$ and $f(x_2)<y$. We conclude by continuity that $f$ must then go through $y$.

Comment: Doesn't something like maximum principle work here?

Comment: Yes, your logic is correct. The continuity argument follows from the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions on $\Bbb R$ by expressing the line segment between $x_1, x_2$ as an imbedding of the unit interval.